# Change VM size after provisioning

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, terraform

How can I downsize a virtual machine after its provisioning, from `terraform` script? Is there a way to update a resource without modifying the initial `.tf` file?

Comment: I got no experience of terraform but this is easily done in the Azure portal. You can visit the VM there and select a new size. This will cause an outage while its being restarted. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/resize-virtual-machines/ for more technical information on what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: I'd like to use `terraform` for that, not a manual operation.

Comment: So you want to use Terraform to change something but without updating your Terraform config?

Comment: Using a trigger or using another `terraform` file, but not modifying the initial script.

Comment: You can import the resource back into terraform. But the idea of Terraform is that it is the source of truth for your resources. You're kinda going against the grain by wanting to make changes but not change the tf files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution, maybe you could try.

1.Copy your tf file, for example `cp vm.tf vm_back.tf` and move `vm.tf` to another directory.

2.Modify `vm_size` in `vm_back.tf`. I use this [tf file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html), so I use the following command to change the value.

```
sed  -i 's/vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"/vm_size               = "Standard_DS2_v2"/g' vm_back.tf
```

3.Update VM size by executing `terraform apply`.

4.Remove vm_back.tf and mv vm.tf to original directory.

Comment: In fact, I more suggest you use [Azure CLi  2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) to do this,  you could use `az vm resize`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_resize).

Comment: I figured out this solution, but I'm looking here and there for a more `terraform` way. May be there is something that can be used on top of `terraform`.

Comment: @Francois Yes, I also think so. Terraform could not do this.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing in a command line argument that is used in a conditional variable?

For example, declare a conditional value in your .tf file:

`vm_size = "${var.vm_size == "small" ? var.small_vm : var.large_vm}"`

And when you want to provision the small VM, you simply pass the vm_size variable in on the command line:

`$ terraform apply -var="vm_size=small"`

Comment: The key question of OP is _"**downsize** a virtual machine **after** its provisioning"_.